# ERROR(UNITY 4.6):"Couldn't read a file://file"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed unity 4.6 but as soon as it finished and I tried to run it, it gives an error, "Couldn't read a file://file" (see the screenshot) and I am not able to run it on my PC. I've also tried to install a different version but they all are giving me the same error message.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Have you tried a re-install? Are you an admin on that machine? Have you tried running Unity or the installer as admin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all Unity files from your computer, than instal Unity 5 from [https://store.unity.com/?_ga=2.113035399.2020539281.1496751500-317263663.1476714068][1]
If you are gonna use Unity 5, if you will not still you can try for is it because your computer or just a temporary bug.

Than install Unity as administrator, read installation process carefull and start as administrator.

I hope that will solve your problem, have a nice day :)